# Need to retrieve a value from an HL7 file using awk

Tags: awk, hl7

In a Linux script program, I've got the following awk command for other purposes and to rename the file.

```
      cat $edifile | awk -F\| '
        { OFS = "|"
          print $0
        } ' | tr -d "\012" > $newname.hl7
```

While this is happening, I'd like to grab the 5th field of the MSH segment and save it for later use in the script.  Is this possible?
If no, how could I do it later or earlier on?
Example of the segment.

MSH|^~\&|business1|business2|/u/tmp/TR0049-GE-1.b64|routing|201811302126||ORU^R01|20181130212105810|D|2.3

What I want to do is retrieve the path and file name in MSH 5 and concatenate it to the end of the new file.

I've used this to capture the data but no luck.  If fpth is getting set, there is no evidence of it and I don't have the right syntax for an echo within the awk phrase.

```
      cat $edifile | awk -F\| '
        { OFS = "|"
          {fpth=$(5)}
          print $0
        } ' | tr -d "\012" > $newname.hl7
```

any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The sample input that I would expect in MSH 5 would be /u/tmp/TR0049-GE-1.b64.  I would have that in $fpth string and then cat the entire file of /u/tmp/TR0049-GE-1.b64 to the end of the newfile after this segment of code is completed.

Comment: Just create an example! Basically you want to parse pipe delimited data, right? What stops you from creating a `hello|i'm|an|example` text segment? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your attempt to set fpth is inside a pair of single quotes.  To your script, that's just a string that it will pass to the awk command.  It's probably best to just add a separate "cat | awk" pipe to output the field you're interested in, and save that to a bash variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
filename=`awk -F'|' '{print $5}' $edifile | head -1`
```

You can skip the piping through *head* if the file is a single line

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it must be mentioned that the `awk` line in your first piece of code, has zero use:

```
$ cat $edifile | awk -F\| ' { OFS = "|"; print $0 }' | tr -d "\012" > $newname.hl7
```

This is totally equivalent to

```
$ cat $edifile | tr -d "\012" > $newname.hl7
```

because `OFS` is only used to redefine `$0` if you redefine a field.

Example:

```
$ echo "a|b|c" | awk -F\| '{OFS="/"; print $0}'
a|b|c
$ echo "a|b|c" | awk -F\| '{OFS="/"; $1=$1; print $0}'
a/b/c
```

I understand that you have a `hl7` file in which you have a single line starting with the string "MSH". From this line you want to store the 5th field: this is achieved in the following way:

```
fpth=$(awk -v outputfile="${newname}.hl7" '
             BEGIN{FS="|"; ORS="" }
             ($1 == "MSH"){ print $5 }
             { print $0 > outputfile }' $edifile)
```

I have replaced ORS to an empty character set, as it is equivalent to `tr -d "\012"`. The above will work very nicely if you only have a single MSH in your file.